# Why $p \subsetneq R \ \text{prime}$ ? why not $p \subseteq R \ \text{prime}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I have some confusion in [wikipedia statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilradical_of_a_ring)

> It is written that  let R be  a  a commutative  ring .Then $$N_R= \bigcap_{p \subsetneq R 
>  \ \text{prime}} p$$

My confusion :  Why $p \subsetneq R 
 \ \text{prime}$ ?  why not $p \subseteq R 
 \ \text{prime}?$

I mean to say that  why not $$N_R= \bigcap_{p \subseteq R 
 \ \text{prime}} p?$$

Suppose $1\in p$. Then for any $r\in R$, we have $r=r. 1 \in p, \implies p=R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually prime ideals are required to be proper by definition. Hence we could argue that $p\subsetneq R$ is redundant, but really no harm is done by mentioning it.